# Cannot connect to Open WiFi hotspot created by Android

Tags: 11.10, wireless, android

I'm trying to share my 3G data connection via WiFi hotspot. I have an open Hotspot running on my phone(Xperia Neo V - MT11i - Android 2.3.4). But I cannot connect to it from my Ubuntu system. Here is the syslog while I try to connect to it -

```
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'TheNeo'
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'TheNeo' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'TheNeo'
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
wpa_supplicant[29352]: Trying to authenticate with 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (SSID='TheNeo' freq=2462 MHz)
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
kernel: [17498.113553] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 1/3)
kernel: [17498.310138] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 2/3)
kernel: [17498.510069] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 3/3)
kernel: [17498.710083] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f timed out
wpa_supplicant[29352]: Trying to authenticate with 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (SSID='TheNeo' freq=2462 MHz)
kernel: [17504.779927] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 1/3)
kernel: [17504.976420] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 2/3)
kernel: [17505.176379] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 3/3)
kernel: [17505.376314] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f timed out
wpa_supplicant[29352]: Trying to authenticate with 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (SSID='TheNeo' freq=2462 MHz)
kernel: [17511.478385] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 1/3)
kernel: [17511.674738] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 2/3)
kernel: [17511.874655] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 3/3)
kernel: [17512.074659] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f timed out
wpa_supplicant[29352]: Trying to authenticate with 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (SSID='TheNeo' freq=2462 MHz)
kernel: [17518.152643] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 1/3)
kernel: [17518.349064] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 2/3)
kernel: [17518.549051] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 3/3)
kernel: [17518.748999] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f timed out
wpa_supplicant[29352]: Trying to authenticate with 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (SSID='TheNeo' freq=2462 MHz)
kernel: [17524.858896] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 1/3)
kernel: [17525.055404] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 2/3)
kernel: [17525.255387] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 3/3)
kernel: [17525.455254] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f timed out
wpa_supplicant[29352]: Trying to authenticate with 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (SSID='TheNeo' freq=2462 MHz)
kernel: [17531.589176] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 1/3)
kernel: [17531.785747] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 2/3)
kernel: [17531.985724] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 3/3)
kernel: [17532.185610] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f timed out
wpa_supplicant[29352]: Trying to authenticate with 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (SSID='TheNeo' freq=2462 MHz)
kernel: [17538.329257] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 1/3)
kernel: [17538.528003] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 2/3)
kernel: [17538.728024] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 3/3)
kernel: [17538.927922] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f timed out
wpa_supplicant[29352]: Trying to authenticate with 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (SSID='TheNeo' freq=2462 MHz)
kernel: [17545.022036] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 1/3)
kernel: [17545.218339] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 2/3)
kernel: [17545.418319] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 3/3)
kernel: [17545.618206] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f timed out
wpa_supplicant[29352]: Trying to authenticate with 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (SSID='TheNeo' freq=2462 MHz)
kernel: [17551.724177] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 1/3)
kernel: [17551.920685] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 2/3)
kernel: [17552.120597] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f (try 3/3)
kernel: [17552.320526] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f timed out
NetworkManager[1077]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long, failing activation.
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout') [50 120 11]
NetworkManager[1077]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for access point (TheNeo)
NetworkManager[1077]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed.
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
NetworkManager[1077]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
NetworkManager[1077]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
```

Why is `direct probe to 5c:b5:24:2f:d1:2f timed out`? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you could also try an alternative app: FoxFi

it works really good for me :)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxfi&hl=en

I dont know if it will work for your phone.

Comment: Doesn't work. It just says there was some error.

Comment: I use Barnacle: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.szym.barnacle&hl=en